# What are advantages of ApplicativeBuilder?

Tags: scalaz, applicative

`Applicative` provides "operator" `<*>`, which I can use as follows:

```
val f: (Int, Int) => Int = {(x, y) => x + y}
1.some <*> (2.some <*> f.curried.some)
```

In addition to that `scalaz` provides `ApplicativeBuilder`:

```
(1.some |@| 2.some)(f)
```

What are advantages of `ApplicativeBuilder` ? When would you use `|@|` instead of `<*>` ?

Comment: Don't forget about `^(1.some, 2.some)(f)`

Comment: Thanks. Did not know about `^`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not really advantages of one over the other, but as you can see the Applicative Builder does not require, that your function is curried and in the context of F. In my opinion it also has a more approachable usage of brackets.

You could also say that the Applicative Builder builds temporary objects, so that you should probably avoid it, when using in very performance critical code and/or loops. In this case you could use another alternative like: `Applicative[Option].apply2(3.some, 4.some)(f)`. This is again very close to the `|@|` syntax, only that you do not have to count the number of parameters you want to provide for `f(n1, n2, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Better type inference

```
scala> ^(1.right[String], 2.right[String])(_ + _)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.\/[String,Int]
 required: ?F[?A]
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method ToAssociativeOps in trait ToAssociativeOps of type [F[_, _], A, B](v: F[A,B])(implicit F0: scalaz.Associative[F])scalaz.syntax.AssociativeOps[F,A,B]
 and method ToBitraverseOps in trait ToBitraverseOps of type [F[_, _], A, B](v: F[A,B])(implicit F0: scalaz.Bitraverse[F])scalaz.syntax.BitraverseOps[F,A,B]
 are possible conversion functions from scalaz.\/[String,Int] to ?F[?A]
              ^(1.right[String], 2.right[String])(_ + _)
                                                 ^

scala> (1.right[String] |@| 2.right[String])(_ + _)
res1: scalaz.\/[String,Int] = \/-(3)
```